# replaced bot laptop fans but will not post

Tags: laptop, fan

Tried replacing my laptop fans (both cpu and gpu), after install laptop wont POST.

troubleshooting done:

removed battery
reset CMOS
reseat fans

all done with both new fans installed and each fans while old fan is installed.

still did not POST.

Tried replacing the fans while laptop is on, new fans work, but old fans will shutdown after a few minutes. will do a restart but will not post.

any ideas on what is happening and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the screen show when you power on the PC while the new fans are plugged in?

Comment: Are you sure you cleaned surfaces and replaced the thermal paste?  Failure to do so will overheat and shut down right away.

Comment: laptop shows nothing, indicator light for charger is on but when pushing the power button the power indicator will turn on for a bit then die off, together with the charging indicator. 
@John did not replace heatpipe just the fans.